# Cambiar el contenido de un div al hacer click con jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, div

Estoy intentando hacer una especie de "cortina" - Un div que muestra un contenido oculto al ser pulsado - y no consigo hacer cambiar el contenido que tiene ese mismo div con jQuery

Aquí os dejo el código que tengo actualmente (sin nada que me cambie el div)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button-show-hide-c3").click(function() {
    $("#show-hide-c3").slideToggle();

  });



});
```

```css
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

#show-hide-c3 {
  display: none;
}

.button-styled {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 20px;
  display: table;
  padding: 20px 0;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column-hard3">
  <div class="container-title-dropdown">
    <h1 class="text-center">Suports de Fixació</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque commodo id ligula id iaculis. Donec vehicula, enim eu semper ultricies, velit nulla placerat orci, vel ultricies est erat sed velit.</p>

  </div>
  <div id="show-hide-c3">
    <div class="container-hardware">
      <div class="margin-container-hardware">
        <div class="part1">
          <a href="_hardware_soportesfijacion-.html">
            <div class="container-go-specs">
              <div class="go-specs-img sup-img"><img src="_style/images/soportes.png" class="zoom" alt="Suports"></div>
              <div class="go-specs">
                <p class="go-specs-text">Més informació</p>
              </div>

            </div>
          </a>

        </div>

        <div class="part2">
          <p>Per als dispositius que han de funcionar en un mostrador de venda o en un passadís de sortida. Allarga la vida del dispositiu...</p>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="button-styled text-center" id="button-show-hide-c3">Mostrar més</div>

</div>

</div>
```

Entonces, necesito que en cuanto el div llega a su posición final, es decir, cuando ya ha mostrado todo el contenido oculto cambie a `"Mostrar menos"` y que cuando le vuelva a pulsar y quede arriba del todo siga saliendo el texto original de `"Mostrar més"`.

He estado buscando también cómo hacerlo en la página de StackOverflow que hay en inglés pero no he sabido implementarlo en mi código.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

Al método slideToggle() puedes pasarle una función callback que se va a ejecutar tras terminar la ejecución de dicho slideToggle(). En ese callback le puedes definir el cambio del texto haciendo `$("#show-hide-c3").html("Mostrar menos");`, sin embargo, lo ideal es que tu función se [mantenga pura](http://www.etnassoft.com/2016/06/21/las-funciones-puras-en-javascript-concepto-ejemplos-y-beneficios/) y que el cambio se haga en función a una referencia y no al elemento en concreto. Por eso, lo ideal es que hagas referencia a `this`.

Para ello tienes dos opciones:

1. Usar una [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions):

Las funciones flecha no asignan el contexto de ejecución a `this` por lo que, en el ejemplo que te pongo, `this` no estaría haciendo referencia al contexto de la función `slideToggle()` sino que estaría haciendo referencia al elemento `$("#show-hide-c3")`, por lo que podrías hacer `$(this).html("Mostrar menos")` y se cambiaría el texto.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button-show-hide-c3").click(function() {
    let flag = $("#show-hide-c3").is(":hidden");
    $("#show-hide-c3").slideToggle('slow', ()=>{
      if(!flag)
        $(this).html("Mostrar més")
      else
        $(this).html("Mostrar menos")
    });
    
  });
});
```

```css
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

#show-hide-c3 {
  display: none;
}

.button-styled {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 20px;
  display: table;
  padding: 20px 0;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column-hard3">
  <div class="container-title-dropdown">
    <h1 class="text-center">Suports de Fixació</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque commodo id ligula id iaculis. Donec vehicula, enim eu semper ultricies, velit nulla placerat orci, vel ultricies est erat sed velit.</p>

  </div>
  <div id="show-hide-c3">
    <div class="container-hardware">
      <div class="margin-container-hardware">
        <div class="part1">
          <a href="_hardware_soportesfijacion-.html">
            <div class="container-go-specs">
              <div class="go-specs-img sup-img"><img src="_style/images/soportes.png" class="zoom" alt="Suports"></div>
              <div class="go-specs">
                <p class="go-specs-text">Més informació</p>
              </div>

            </div>
          </a>

        </div>

        <div class="part2">
          <p>Per als dispositius que han de funcionar en un mostrador de venda o en un passadís de sortida. Allarga la vida del dispositiu...</p>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="button-styled text-center" id="button-show-hide-c3">Mostrar més</div>

</div>

</div>
```

2. Guardar `this` antes de llamar a `slideToggle()`:

Así te aseguras que, dentro del `slideToggle()`, `this` hace referencia al elemento:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button-show-hide-c3").click(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    let flag = $("#show-hide-c3").is(":hidden");
    $("#show-hide-c3").slideToggle('slow', function(){
    if(flag)
      $(that).html("Mostrar menos");
    else
      $(that).html("Mostrar més");
    }
    );
  });
});
```

```css
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

#show-hide-c3 {
  display: none;
}

.button-styled {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 20px;
  display: table;
  padding: 20px 0;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column-hard3">
  <div class="container-title-dropdown">
    <h1 class="text-center">Suports de Fixació</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque commodo id ligula id iaculis. Donec vehicula, enim eu semper ultricies, velit nulla placerat orci, vel ultricies est erat sed velit.</p>

  </div>
  <div id="show-hide-c3">
    <div class="container-hardware">
      <div class="margin-container-hardware">
        <div class="part1">
          <a href="_hardware_soportesfijacion-.html">
            <div class="container-go-specs">
              <div class="go-specs-img sup-img"><img src="_style/images/soportes.png" class="zoom" alt="Suports"></div>
              <div class="go-specs">
                <p class="go-specs-text">Més informació</p>
              </div>

            </div>
          </a>

        </div>

        <div class="part2">
          <p>Per als dispositius que han de funcionar en un mostrador de venda o en un passadís de sortida. Allarga la vida del dispositiu...</p>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="button-styled text-center" id="button-show-hide-c3">Mostrar més</div>

</div>

</div>
```

Personalmente, la primera opción (utilizando funciones flecha) me parece la más limpia y la que mejor te ayuda a controlar tu código.

**EDITO**: He añadido un `flag` para saber si el `div` está desplegado o no y cambiar el valor del texto en función de cómo esté.

Comment: Buah, por fin! Muchísimas gracias. Había estado intentando aplicar soluciones de otras preguntas, pero se me superponían los textos, o no me funcionaba la función.

Answer (score 0):

a .slideToggle() le puedes pasar como argumento la función que quieres que se ejecute cuando se complete, puedes consultarlo en la docu de JQuery:
[Documentación JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

Además, aquí te dejo otro link con la implementación de otro compañero de Stackoverflow EN:
[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975788/call-function-after-slidetoggle-complete)